# VSCode Search text in files API

Tags: vscode-extensions

is there an API that returns the search results in a workspace like in the search tab. The only thing i could find is this proposed api from 2018,
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_proposed-extension-apis

[image]